# Python/Tkinter - strange insert instead of replace during Entry validation

Tags: python, validation, tkinter

Here is simple Python/Tkinter program with single Entry widget that i want automatically check is number entered or not.

```py
from Tkinter import *

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.myParent = parent
        self.portVar = IntVar()
        self.portVar.set(111)

        port_validator = self.myParent.register(self._validate)

        self.myEntry = Entry(self.myParent, width=9, textvariable=self.portVar,
            validate='all', validatecommand=(port_validator,'%d', '%i', '%P', '%s', '%S', '%v', '%V', '%W'))

        self.myEntry.pack(side=TOP)


    def _validate(self, d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W):
        print "OnValidate: d='%s' i='%s' P='%s' s='%s' S='%s' v='%s' V='%s' W='%s'" % (d, i, P, s, S, v, V, W)
        return P.isdigit()


root = Tk()
myclass = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

print statement in _validate() function only for debugging.
The problem is in this case visual editing of Entry is incorrect.
For example i doing those steps:

1. Launch program.
2. See '111' value in the Entry
3. Select '111' by left mouse button
4. Press "9" on keyboard
5. Instead of full replace '111' to '9' insert happens and i see '9111'!

Debug log (i numerated steps for convinience):

1. OnValidate: d='-1' i='-1' P='111' s='' S='' v='all' V='forced' W='.37125736'
2. OnValidate: d='-1' i='-1' P='111' s='111' S='' v='all' V='focusin' W='.37125736'
3. OnValidate: d='0' i='0' P='' s='111' S='111' v='all' V='key' W='.37125736'
4. OnValidate: d='1' i='0' **P='9111'** s='111' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37125736'
5. OnValidate: d='0' i='1' P='9' s='9111' S='111' v='all' V='key' W='.37125736'
6. OnValidate: d='1' i='1' P='99' s='9' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37125736'
7. OnValidate: d='1' i='2' P='999' s='99' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37125736'

Pay attention to step 4. It is strange additional step with unwanted Entry text state ('9111')

But if i change

```
return P.isdigit()
```

to

```
return True
```

Everything becomes ok! Entry works like any entry in other programs.

```
1. OnValidate: d='-1' i='-1' P='111' s='' S='' v='all' V='forced' W='.37650024'
2. OnValidate: d='-1' i='-1' P='111' s='111' S='' v='all' V='focusin' W='.37650024'
3. OnValidate: d='0' i='0' P='' s='111' S='111' v='all' V='key' W='.37650024'
4. OnValidate: d='1' i='0' P='9' s='' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37650024'
5. OnValidate: d='1' i='1' P='99' s='9' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37650024'
6. OnValidate: d='1' i='2' P='999' s='99' S='9' v='all' V='key' W='.37650024'
```

Why, guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because with `P.isdigit()` you are restricting the content to be a digit. When you replace 111 to 9, there is a step in which the content of the entry is an empty string. Since `''.isdigit()` is false, the widget always keep a digit as its content. Removing this constraint you allow any string, and then you can fully replace the value.